# Однокоренные ли слова?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Слова "любить", "любимый", "любый" и "любой" - однокоренные? То есть, понятно, что первые три - однокоренные, но "любой"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ДА. эти слова исторические родственники.
ЛЮБОЙ - Общеславянское. Измененная форма слова  любый ( "милый, дорогой" ). Исходное значение — "возбуждающий неодолимое желание", затем — "любимый, милый, дорогой", далее — "тот, который при свободе выбора нравится больше" и, наконец, — "всякий".